# Undefined Index when passing data to different HTML5 page

Tags: php, html, forms, post

The following is one of my HTML pages.

```
<form id="regForm" method="post" action="enquiry_process.php" novalidate="novalidate">

<fieldset>
    <legend>Personal Details</legend>

      <label>First Name:</label>
          <input  type="text" name="owner" id="owner"  /><br />

        <label>Last Name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="owner2" id="owner2" /><br />
</fieldset>

 <p>
    <input type="Submit" onclick="validateForm()"/>
    <input type="Reset" value="Reset" />
</p>

</form>
```

The following is my 2nd HTML page.

```
<form id="bookForm" method="post" action="view_enquiry.php">

<?php
        $fname = $_POST['owner'];
        $lname = $_POST['owner2'];
?>

        <input type="hidden" name="owner" value="<?php echo $fname; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="owner2" value="<?php echo $lname; ?>">

<fieldset>
            <legend>User Details</legend>
            <p>Your First Name: <span id="confirm_fname"></span></p>
            <p>Your Last Name: <span id="confirm_lname"></span></p>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Confirm Booking" />
<input type="button" value="Cancel" id="cancelButton" onclick="cancelBooking()" />

</fieldset>
```

The functions you see like `validateForm()` and `cancelBooking()` are Javascript functions that validate my form or return the user from the 2nd page to the 1st and I believe they have nothing to do with my question.

When I click submit on the first HTML page, it should pass on the value of the `owner` and `owner2` to the 2nd page right?

I keep on getting Undefined index and after looking around, it seems like I have to use `isset()` or `empty()` in my PHP, but this seems to only mask my notices but does not actually fix it? When I just add `isset()`, it ends up giving my 3rd page **Undefined Variable**. The `method` on my forms are already `post`.

Is there another problem here? Thank you.

EDIT: The following is are my relevant Javascripts.

ValidateForm:

```
function validateForm(){
    "use strict";


    gErrorMsg = "";
    var nameOK = chkOwnerName();

    var nameOK2 = chkOwnerName2();

    var isAllOK = (nameOK && nameOK2);
    if(isAllOK){

        isAllOK = storeBooking();
    }
    else{
        alert(gErrorMsg);
        gErrorMsg = "";

    }
    return isAllOK;
    }
```

Storebooking:

```
function storeBooking() {

"use strict";
sessionStorage.firstname =   document.getElementById("owner").value;
sessionStorage.lastname =    document.getElementById("owner2").value;
window.location = "enquiry_process.php";
}
```

I have another function called `getbooking` that runs with the condition `window.onload`

```
function getBooking(){
 //if sessionStorage for username is not empty

 if((sessionStorage.firstname != undefined)){
 //confirmation text

 document.getElementById("confirm_fname").textContent = sessionStorage.firstname;

 document.getElementById("confirm_lname").textContent = sessionStorage.lastname;

}
```

`chkOwnerName` and `chkOwnerName2` are functions that validate the form with patterns and I don't think they're relevant.

I also updated my 2nd HTML page with Javascript related contents because I assumed it wasn't relevant at first.

Comment: Can you attach complete both html pages?

Comment: The other things in the pages are just headings and footers

Comment: I am trying offline at my end but no issue is coming

Comment: values are going fine from first form to second form. where is the issue actually coming?

Comment: The values are going nicely with my Javascript to `confirm_fname` and `confirm_lname`, thats why I assumed it didn't matter. I keep on getting **Notice: Undefined index** for  `owner` and `owner2`

Comment: add echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); die; at top of your 2nd form and send me the output here

Comment: I want to see form data is coming in your 2nd form or not

Comment: All it says is **Array()** ; EDIT: I see the problem now. Thank you. I had other fields in the form and one of them was an array that wasn't functioning properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159843/discussion-between-amit-gupta-and-raph).

Comment: Accept my answer if your issue is resolved now and upvote :) Happy coding..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can debug with below code by adding it in your 2nd form page.

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); die;
```

If your form data is not going to your 2nd form then Array() will come as empty.

Answer (score 0):

"if(empty($var))" and "if(isset($var))" are conditions, they check something and execute code within "{}" if the test returns true. So they don't 'fix' problems.

Your script worked fine for me without your js. Maybe the problem.

Just try your code step by step. You will find what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

u can try by `print_r($_REQUEST[]);` on second form top page (`enquiry_process.php`) , i hope the both the form is in same folder and name of second form page is `"enquiry_process.php"` .

Since u r sending data using post form u should be able to retrieve it by `print_r($_POST);` or `print_r($_REQUEST);`

Comment: They are in the same folder but I don't understand what you meant. Can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: You can just write down print_r($_POST); on first line of `enquiry_process.php` page to confirm if data is sended via form1 is received in post array or not.

Comment: I did not but I'll get it back to 0 for you